# I want to make a child linear layout invisible during onCreate and then make it visible at the tap of a button

Tags: java, xml

[XML Layout Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydTht.png) This is my layout. I want everything after the button to be invisible until the button is tapped.

```
/**
     * This activity toggles open the order_form layout AFTER "Order" Button is clicked.
     */
    Button properties = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order_button);

// and LinearLayout to toggle
    final LinearLayout propLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.order_form);

    properties.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            propLayout.setVisibility((propLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    ? View.INVISIBLE
                    : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

place and visibility attribute in xml
like so

> android:visibility="invisible"

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:visibility="invisible">

   <-- edittext views here-->
   <EditText
      ......./>
</LinerLayout>
```

Comment: Please explain further? I had used "invisible" before now and it still returned error.

Comment: Thanks all. This issue have been solved by moving the activity method to right after the onCreate method. Before i had it under another method. Thereby the onCreate overrode it.